# Upload file then unzip as well as writing a query to the database

Tags: php, sql, file-upload

I have an upload system where I want to be able to upload .zip files then for it to unzip. My uploading/unzipping works fine, but when I choose what file I want to upload, I want to be able to type something down in a text field, then when I click Upload it will upload the zip then upzip the files, then it would insert a field into the database with the zip/folder name.

The upload code:

```
function rmdir_recursive($dir) {
    foreach(scandir($dir) as $file) {
       if ('.' === $file || '..' === $file) continue;
       if (is_dir("$dir/$file")) rmdir_recursive("$dir/$file");
       else unlink("$dir/$file");
   }

   rmdir($dir);
}

if($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"]) {
    $filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
    $source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
    $type = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];

    $name = explode(".", $filename);
    $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
    foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
        if($mime_type == $type) {
            $okay = true;
            break;
        } 
    }

    $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
    if(!$continue) {
        $message = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
    }

  /* PHP current path */
  $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';  // absolute path to the directory where zipper.php is in
  $filenoext = basename ($filename, '.zip');  // absolute path to the directory where zipper.php is in (lowercase)
  $filenoext = basename ($filenoext, '.ZIP');  // absolute path to the directory where zipper.php is in (when uppercase)

  $targetdir = $path . $filenoext; // target directory
  $targetzip = $path . $filename; // target zip file

  /* create directory if not exists', otherwise overwrite */
  /* target directory is same as filename without extension */

  if (is_dir($targetdir))  rmdir_recursive ( $targetdir);


  mkdir($targetdir, 0777);


  /* here it is really happening */

    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $targetzip)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $x = $zip->open($targetzip);  // open the zip file to extract
        if ($x === true) {
            $zip->extractTo($targetdir); // place in the directory with same name  
            $zip->close();

            unlink($targetzip);
        }
        $message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";

    } else {    
        $message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
    }
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Unzip a zip file to the webserver</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php if($message) echo "<p>$message</p>"; ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<label>Choose a zip file to upload: <input type="file" name="zip_file" /></label>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How would I be able to put a text input in my upload so when I press 'Upload' the zip will upload but the text in my input field will be recorded in a databse table.

Comment: Add it as a named `<input>` to your form and read it from the $_POST array.